# Cannot log in to WordPress admin or change password

Tags: wp-admin

I have a WordPress website at costumesymposium.org.uk.wp which I have not yet migrated to the local host.  Recently I received an email saying that the site had automatically been upgraded to wp version 4.9.9.  I am not able to log in to wp admin any more.

I tried changing the password via PHP MyAdmin several times and was still unable to log in.  I have changed the password line in wp_users back to what it was before.

I also checked db_version in WP_Options and found it is 38590 while the number for 4.9.9 is 43764.  Online forums suggest I should see if this matches the field wp_db_version of version.php in Version.php located under wp-include in the folder of the wordpress blog, but I can't find the file to compare them.  Where should I find this file?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

I don't understand code and am completely stuck as I can't do anything without being able to log in to wp-admin.

I checked version.php located under wp-include and it shows

/**
 * Holds the WordPress DB revision, increments when changes are made to the WordPress DB schema.
 *
 * @global int $wp_db_version
 */
$wp_db_version = 38590;

So the number matches the version number in WP_options but that number is for version 4.9.8 (which is what I originally installed) and the number for the automatically upgraded version 4.9.9 is 47364.  What would happen if I change the number to the latest version?  Or should I reinstall Wordpress 4.9.9?

Comment: Confirm the database you are using for the site in wp-config.php is the one you are editing with PHPMyAdmin

Comment: I found this in wp-config.php: /** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'c8328238_wp640');  This is the correct name of the only database I have.

Answer (score 0):

After trying almost everything suggested here and elsewhere, I switched browsers to Chrome and was able to log in.  Could there be some incompatibility between Wordpress updates and older versions of Firefox and Safari?